# Why the parent should die, in the process of creating a Daemon

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, fork, daemon

" ***Thus, the common method for launching a daemon involves forking  once or twice, and making the parent processes die while the child process begins performing its normal function.***" 
I was going through OS concepts and I didn't understand the above said lines.
Why the parent process will be made to exit( or parent dying ),in the process of creating a Daemon?
Can someone pls explain me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, a daemon process is defined as a process whose parent is the system's init process and which runs in the background. For instance, if you were to execute some program in your terminal, your shell would create a process (either in the foreground or background) and the program would run with your shell as its parent. This is an example of a non-daemon process because its parent is your shell process.

So how do you produce a process whose parent is the init process? Well, a process whose parent process dies before it (the child) has exited becomes an orphan process. An orphan process will in turn be re-parented to the init process. Voila, the process now meets the definition of a daemon.

Tying this back to your quote, if you were to fork once and then kill the parent, you achieve the desired effect. Likewise, if you fork once and then have that child fork another process, followed by killing the first child, you also achieve the desired effect while keeping the (now grandparent) process alive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro.I understood the first two paragraphs perfectly, but i couldn't exactly get the last paragraph, i.e.., regarding the forking the child again. We r meeting the requirement of daemon by killing the parent,then y do v need to fork the child again.Apologies if my understanding was wrong.

Comment: I think you have the right understanding. The second example where two children are forked is just another way of producing a daemon while keeping the first process alive. So: `grandparent -> child -> grandchild (daemon)`. In this scenario, we do not kill the grandparent. Instead, the grandparent's child forks another process that will become the daemon. We kill that first child (the middle process in the diagram) which leaves us with the grandparent and the grandchild (which has now become a daemon). This way we produce a daemon while keeping the first process alive.

Comment: Got it Bro.. Thank u very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a requirement, as any background process could be a daemon. Technically a daemon process in one that runs to operate some general non interactive task. In Unix environment, a daemon is generally set as a process that have some characteristics: no controlling terminal, no umask, particular working directory, etc. Forking twice is a common way to obtain the grandchild to be inherited by init process and have the former properties, in some way to get a process fully detached of any user control (except root of course).

This applies only if a standard user want to create a daemon. Some other standard daemons are created almost normally (see init, launchd, etc)

Answer (score 1):

If the parent exits while the daemon continues running, the daemon is orphaned, and the `init` process typically adopts it (i.e. becomes the parent).

There are some exceptions, but it is normally expected that a daemon process will be descended from the `init` process (e.g. the `init` process will launch daemons during system startup).  So, if another process launches a daemon and terminates, it achieves the desired effect.

Note that some other actions are also needed, such as disassociating the daemon from any tty window.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers already explained what happens when parent dies i.e. child is adopted by init process.

But why above is required to make a process daemon? A daemon by definition is non-interacting program i.e. it should not be associated with a terminal. That ensures that daemon continues to work in background even when user sends signals by Control-C, hangup etc. Now, how to prevent a process from ever attaching to a terminal? Make init it's parent by killing original parent. 
**init** is a special process because:

- It's not attached to any terminal.
- It's first process (pid 1) after booting OS, and that makes it leader of it's session. Note that every UNIX process belongs a process group and that in turn belongs to a session. First process in the session becomes session leader.

In UNIX, only session leader can attach to (or control) terminal. As soon as you make ***init*** parent of your process, it joins init's session. Since init is the session leader, your process can never be the leader and hence can never attach to a terminal. That's what we wanted, right?

There are other ways to detach terminal e.g. calling setsid but that's not part of this discussion.